# Using graphics.py my horizontal line is showing up in the wrong place

Tags: python, python-2.7, line, zelle-graphics

```
def main():
    win=GraphWin('Test',400,400)
    line=Line(Point(50,50),Point(350,50))
    line.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

[What comes out:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7UGZ.png)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

What I expect:
The window is 400 by 400. The first point should be 50 units to the right and 50 units up. The second point should be 350 units to the right and 50 units up. The line should connect those points which should appear close to the bottom of the window.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you expect.

Comment: The window is 400 by 400. The first point should be 50 units to the right and 50 units up. The second point should be 350 units to the right and 50 units up. The line should connect those points which should appear close to the bottom of the window. Am I thinking of this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're expecting Zelle graphics to be plotting in a different quadrant than is does.  It sounds like you're expecting to be in the upper left quadrant with the origin at the lower left but in fact you are in the lower right quadrant with the origin at the upper left.  Here's a slight modification to your program to orient you:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin('Test', 400, 400)

Line(Point(5, 5), Point(400, 5)).draw(win)
Line(Point(5, 5), Point(5, 400)).draw(win)

line = Line(Point(50, 50), Point(350, 50))
line.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

**Annotated Output**

[image]

However, rather than change your model of the world, you can ask Zelle graphics to change it's point of view via `setCoords(xll, yll, xur, yur)`:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin('Test', 400, 400)
win.setCoords(0, 0, 400, 400)

Line(Point(5, 5), Point(400, 5)).draw(win)
Line(Point(5, 5), Point(5, 400)).draw(win)

line = Line(Point(50, 50), Point(350, 50))
line.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

**Unannotated Output**

[image]